# "Input is provided as CSV format via STDIN"

Tags: c++, csv, stdin

I'm working on a programming problem in C++, where I need to write a CSV parser. I've written this before for files, but the instructions state:

> Input is provided as CSV format via STDIN. The first line is a header. The subsequent lines are data.

Here's an example of the input "file":

```
#id,time,amount
0,4,5
2,8,3
8,1,2
...
```

Now I'm a bit confused by this because I haven't worked with STDIN much since picking up C++ a few years ago. How exactly does one read in a csv file through STDIN? When I've used `std::cin` in the past, if I try to paste multiple lines, only the first line will get read.

The instructions of the programming problem did not make it clear how the input "file" will be fed in through STDIN, or perhaps there's some classical way it's done and my lack of knowledge makes me think it's unclear? Is there some standard way a CSV file is read in through STDIN?

All I am tasked to do is to process what comes through STDIN, and I'm not given how things are passed into STDIN. I feel like I need to know how things are passed in to know what I'm supposed to do? Like it could be passed in character by character, line by line, entry by entry, or the entire file at a time?

Comment: Use cin instead of ifstream

Comment: It usually looks something like `myprogram < myfile.csv` on the command line

Comment: "*When I've used std::cin in the past, if I try to paste multiple lines, only the first line will get read*" - then either you were not reading the lines correctly, or your console was truncating them before they reached your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think I worded that incorrectly. When I said that I was thinking if the entire file may be copy and pasted onto the command line on a single line and then passed through STDIN. In that case I think only the first line will get read in to the program?

Comment: It will most likely be the same as if you read the file. I expect it will be as the second comment stated.

Comment: ***pasted onto the command line on a single line*** Would not be through STDIN. That would be command line arguments

Comment: @drescherjm Doesn't `std::cin` use STDIN? When I use `std::cin`, it's just read through the command line?

Comment: I thought you meant physically typing  `myexe 0,4,5,2,8,3 ...` where myexe is your executable

Comment: @drescherjm Oh I meant first running the executable and then copying and pasting the contents

Comment: That should be the same as comment #2 which uses the OS shell to do that. In that case the code would be just using cin instead of ifstream

Comment: @roulette01 copy/pasting AFTER the program is running SHOULD appear in `STDIN`/`std::cin`, yes, but I can imagine the console window MAY truncate the text, sending only the 1st line at a time to the app. Using file input redirection (`myprogram < myfile.csv`) would be a more reliable way to get multi-line data into the program on `STDIN`/`std::cin`.  There is really nothing special about reading from `std::cin` vs `std::ifstream`, they are both `std::istream` descendants.